# What are the grammatical rules determining whether to use "which" or "what"?

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns

What are the grammatical rules determining whether to use *which* or *what*?

I usually go by intuition. It's "What car are you looking at?" and "What bicycle do you like most?" but "Which song did you sing?" Quite often, I don't know whether to use *what* or *which*.

How can I tell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Which** is used when there is a selection of choices, and you are picking one.

**What** is used for a description, or if you don't know what the choices are.

For your examples, it should be:

> ***Which*** car are you looking at?

This is because you are probably next to your friend and have an idea of the selection of choices.

> ***Which*** bicycle do you like most?

I'm assuming here that you are both in a store or looking at the same webpage, so that you know your choices.

> ***What*** song did you just sing?

Here, you don't know the choices that were picked from, so you use *what*

Answer (score 7):

There really isn't a whole lot of difference. Although *which* may be slightly more formal, *what* may be used without occasioning discomfort.

That said, *which* does seem to narrow the range of choices somewhat. If I say

> What car do you drive?

that leaves the possible answers open to the set of all cars, whereas

> Which car do you drive?

may feel like a question you would ask about a finite set of automobiles, the choices being limited to, say, your car or your wife's.

But this is not a hard-and-fast rule.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3414/31820) at EL&U.SE (and other answers to [the same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3413/31820)):

- *Which* is more formal than *What*; *which* can be a replacement for *what* (but not the opposite).
- *Which* is more suitable for selecting from a finite set of choices; *what* is more open-ended.

For example, contrast *which one do you want to eat?* (when selecting from a menu) and *what do you want to eat?* (when you want suggestions to make a menu).

In this case, *which* is not a good replacement for *what*, and the opposite replacement isn't very good either.

Comment: Usage niggle: "isn't very good, too" would be better as "isn't very good either".

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks: I was thinking in Portuguese (where the same word means 'too' and 'either').