# Is it more appropriate to use WHAT or WHICH in this question?

Tags: wh-questions

I am wanting to know who rules Canada. Should I ask:

"By WHAT monarch is Canada ruled?"
or "By WHICH monarch is Canada ruled?"

(The answer would be: "Canada is ruled by the British monarch Elisabeth the second.")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the grammatical rules determining whether to use "which" or "what"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117/what-are-the-grammatical-rules-determining-whether-to-use-which-or-what) In your exact context both are fine, but ***which*** more strongly implies that speaker and/or respondent ***already know the list*** of "candidate monarchs" from which the answer will be drawn.

Comment: ...note that we wouldn't generally use ***to be ruled by*** in such contexts today. It's true the Queen is in fact the "constitutional monarch" of Canada, but she has no actual *power* (she only ever does or says whatever the Canadian government tell her; she's just a "titular head of state").

Comment: The Queen "reigns but does not rule". This has been the case in Canada since the Treaty of Paris ended the reign of Canada's last absolute monarch, Louis XV of France. However, the royal prerogative belongs to the Crown and not to any of the ministers and the royal and viceroyal figures may unilaterally use these powers in exceptional constitutional crisis situations.

Answer (score 2):

> "By WHAT monarch is Canada ruled?" or "By WHICH monarch is Canada
> ruled?"

Let us set aside the matter of whether a monarch rules or reigns over Canada. It is interesting from a factual point of view but it's not grammatically relevant.

**By what monarch is Canada ruled?**

This presupposes that Canada is ruled by a monarch. The question merely asks for their name. No account is taken of other monarchs that may exist elsewhere.

**By which monarch is Canada ruled?**

This presupposes that there are several monarchs who are candidates for ruling Canada. You are asked to choose one and name them.

So, the answer will be the same in both cases. It is just the presuppositions that differ.

Comment: By the way, can I put that question this way: "What monarch is Canada ruled by?"

Comment: A few grammarians still insist that one should not end a sentence with a preposition. However that view is becoming less and less popular.  Let's just say that your original version is more formal (and might be used in a quiz) and the one you have just mentioned is less formal.  More idiomatic in conversation is, "Which monarch is the ruler of Canada?"